# about Key error in python using jupyter notebook

Tags: python

I am new to machine learning using python..i have attache te code which gives mi key error. I did'nt understand how to remove it.

```
min(target['target'])
```

shows error like:
`KeyError: ' target'`

Comment: It's telling you your `target` dictionary has no key `target`. What else can one say without seeing the dictionary?

Comment: Please `print(target)` and add it to your question.

Comment: @AllaTarighati better use pprint